# Remove string from template literal types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have been able to express this as a function such that `foo` returns the string without the 'Bar' at the end. However, how do you manage the same thing using the `type` statement? (see below)

```js
declare function foo<T extends string>(str: `${T}Bar`): T;
const justFoo = foo('fooBar');

// justFoo now exactly matches the type 'foo'

// What goes here?
type Foo<T extends string> = T;
type JustFoo = Foo<'fooBar'>;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `infer` to grab the type from that spot:

```
type Foo<T extends string> = T extends `${infer Prefix}Bar` ? Prefix : never;
```

This says to check if the string end in `"Bar"`, and if it does, then infer the contents of the string before the bar and return that as the type. If the string does not end in `"Bar"` then set the type to `never`, which should result in a type error when you try to use it.

[Working Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwB4AVeEADwxFWAGd46MYtUBzAPgAomYAueAAMAJAG8SAXwBCsQQEoBJANwBYAFBg8TeACtkTAGKF4AXgI4uAckSEZMS3NVr1Aehe79GIzniocAd3IKKEwIAE94AFsoDDAACxAGDAT4DDCABwRrQkt1V3cAdTiY+DYcRPgEuAB+dTTM+G9SIOpaBl5WTlN4MkpW+iExVkQQGHgABThELAppWXhqiamZ+AFUEAA3Uad6hAApT29upuycO0sOJ3VNVG0Dw2MzU8t4N3h-HBgAazogA)

---

You could even contrain the generic so that it can never be `never`.

```
type Foo<T extends `${string}Bar`> = T extends `${infer Prefix}Bar` ? Prefix : never;
type JustFoo = Foo<'fooBar'>; // works
type ExpectErrorHere = Foo<'nofoofoyoo'> // error as expected
```

In this example:

```
T extends `${infer Prefix}Bar`
```

Cannot be false, so the `never` clause will not be used. However, `infer` *must* be used from a conditional type. So you still have to check it.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwB4AVeEADwxFWAGd46MYtUBzAPgAomYAueAAMAJAG8SAXwBCsQQEoBJANwBYAFBg8TeACtkTAGKF4AXgI4uAckSEZMS3NVr1Aehe79GIzniocAd3IKKEwIAE94AFsoDDAACxAGDAT4DDCABwRrQkt1V3cAdTiY+DYcRPgEuAB+dTTM+G9SIOpaBhFRXlY2aVkOU3gySlb6ITFWRBAYeAAFOEQsCl6YQXhq2fnF+AFUEAA3Kad6hAApT28BpuycO0sOJ3VNVG0zw2Mza8t4N3h-HBgANZ0PJqY7wACiFEymHBMBg-wAElMEGYrn4bDgbGEcv0fpRodRgOQ4f8ADSlHAYYnwmDkso4YAAQiAA)

Comment: Tidy answer; thanks very much! Small thing I noticed was `const JustFoo = 'foo'` isn't constrained by anything in your playground examples. Other than that this is spot on!